# Should I replace this dryer vent duct w/ semi-rigid or rigid metal?

Tags: dryer, ducts, product-recommendation

I'm a new home owner, and have been trying to look for ways to keep my house in fighting shape. Going down the rabbit hole I learned, some types of dryer vent ducts are very flammable. This prompted me to check what I had, and I think mine is the most flammable of them all. Which duct type should I replace this with?

[image: dryer vent duct]

Comment: Usually it is the lint inside from not cleaning that is the problem, but if you can reduce one elbow, that should make the exhaust work easier.  Rigid metal is the smoothest inside and the easiest to clean.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start with that and see how far I get.

Comment: Clean it and shorten it to the shortest you can get away with while preserving the ability to get the dryer out far enough to service it. That will help to reduce your chance of fire.

Comment: I would replace as much of the flex duct as possible with rigid (aluminum?).  Then just use a short section of flex to make the final connection to the dryer.

Comment: A periscope duct may serve you well in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's 4" flex foil duct, and yes it is flammable.  Hardware stores are crazy for advertising this for dryer venting.

Semi-rigid duct will be the easiest material to work with.  Look for the one that's UL rated, not the cheap junk.

Rigid duct would also work here as it looks like the wall opening is more than 4" above the floor.

For either material, follow the dryer instructions.  Do not leave excess material laying on the floor when a shorter length will suffice.

Comment: Thanks. I freaked out when I watched a video showing just how fast and easy this stuff burns. Not entirely sure, why it is even available for purchase.

Comment: @stackback Flex foil duct is a cheap solution for fan venting, where it is unlikely to be a fire hazard.